# How to handle loops better in pymc?

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc

I am trying to do some Bayesian analysis for models like [markovian switching multi-fractal](https://www.nber.org/papers/w9839). Basically, at each state, we decide to switch one volatility component to a new value(sample) or not. Currently, I use a naive approach to loop through the time and create a volatility variable for each time t.

```
import pymc as pm
import pytensor.tensor as pt

with pm.Model() as MSM:
    phi = pm.Uniform("phi",lower=0,upper=1)
    sig = pm.Gamma("sig", alpha=2, beta=1)
    gamma_A = pm.Uniform("gamma_A",lower=0,upper=1)
    rm_A = pm.HalfNormal("rm_A", sigma=0.1)
    rA = rm_A + 1
    a = pm.Gamma("a", alpha=2, beta=1)

    gamma_A1 = gamma_A
    gamma_A2 = gamma_A ** rA
    gamma_A3 = gamma_A ** (rA * rA)

    PA1 = pm.Bernoulli("PA1", p=gamma_A1, shape=(T-1,))
    PA2 = pm.Bernoulli("PA2", p=gamma_A2, shape=(T-1,))
    PA3 = pm.Bernoulli("PA3", p=gamma_A3, shape=(T-1,))

    A1 = pm.LogNormal("A1", mu=-a**2/2, sigma=a, shape=(T,))
    A2 = pm.LogNormal("A2", mu=-a**2/2, sigma=a, shape=(T,))
    A3 = pm.LogNormal("A3", mu=-a**2/2, sigma=a, shape=(T,))

    A1_t, A2_t, A3_t, B1_t, B2_t, B3_t = [A1[0]],[A2[0]],[A3[0]],[B1[0]],[B2[0]],[B3[0]]
    for i in range(1,T):
        A1_t.append(A1_t[i-1]*(PA1[i-1]) + A1[i] * (1-PA1[i-1]))
        A2_t.append(A2_t[i-1]*(PA2[i-1]) + A2[i] * (1-PA2[i-1]))
        A3_t.append(A3_t[i-1]*(PA3[i-1]) + A3[i] * (1-PA3[i-1]))

    A1_t = pt.stack(A1_t)
    A2_t = pt.stack(A2_t)
    A3_t = pt.stack(A3_t)
        
    A_t = A1_t * A2_t * A3_t

    sig_t = sig * pt.sqrt(A_t)

    yobs = pm.Normal("yobs", mu=phi*x, sigma=sig_t, observed=y)

    posterior = pm.sample(10000, tune=1000)
```

However, this only works in small time series, up to about 50 samples. When I try to work with series of hundreds samples, the program will throw 'UserWarning: Loop fusion failed because the resulting node would exceed the kernel argument limit'. I would like to know if there is better ways to do this kind of loops in pymc, and perhaps improve performance?